# Can't add a reviewer for github pull request

Tags: github, review

I am the owner of public github repository, but can't add anyone to review my pull request.
It only shows "Nothing to show", regardless the nickname I write.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iODL.png)

Comment: Has anyone else been explicitly granted read, write, or admin access on this repo?

Comment: No, it's just a default repository with no additional setups

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to give access to your repository by inviting the user to become a collaborator. Open your repository, go to Settings => Manage Access, and click "Invite a collaborator". This information is from Github Support.

Comment: Can I request a review from person, without granting him collaborator access?

Comment: 'You're only able to request reviews from your repository's collaborators' -- GitHub Developer Support.

Comment: I have the same problem and I cannot assign a Collaborator already participating in the repo.